# Show Post Count For User Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show the amount of posts each users on my WP site has posted.

Currently the code I have is:

```
<?php
$author_id = the_author_meta('ID');
echo count_user_posts('$author_id');
?>
```

As you can see I am storing the author ID in `$author_id` and running that in the `count_user_posts()` echo.

When I run the to strings separately it works however when, I combine them as above it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use get_the_author_meta for this kind of purposes.

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
echo count_user_posts($author_id);
```

the_author_meta should be used only for echoing stuff.

Comment: Thats the one! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like this :

```
<?php
$author_id = the_author_meta('ID');
echo count_user_posts($author_id); // remove quotes
?>
```

Hope it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

I found you need to add your post, page or your_custom_post_type for it to work successfully.

```
<?php echo 'Posts made: ' .(count_user_posts(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'your_custom_post_type') );  ?>

// or multiple post types

<?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta('ID'),['job', 'featured_job', 'free_job'] ); ?>
```